# How to get checkbox value on alert using jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#city").change(function(){
            name = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
               type:"GET",
               dataType: "json",
               data:{name: name},
               dataType: 'json',
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               url:"test.php",
               async:false,
               success:function(data)
               {
                    $.each(data.PostOffice, function(key, item) {

                        $("#pincode").append("<li><input type='checkbox' id='"+item.PINCode+"' name='pin' class='pin'/>"+item.Name+"</li>");
                    });
               }
            });
        });

        $(".pin").on('click',function(){
            pin = this.id;
            alert(pincode);
        });
    });
</script>
```

In this code I am using `append` function inside the `each` loop as you can see above the code. Now, What happen I have multiple checkbox when I change `city` but when I use `$(".pin").on('click',function(){` to get the `id` of checkbox it doesn't work. So, How can I get `id` onclick `class="pin"`? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: Sidenote - `dataType: 'json',` used twice.

Comment: `alert(pincode);` where is `pincode` set? Do you want to `alert(pin);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are adding the HTML for checkbox inside `AJAX` call dynamically after the page has been loaded, the function `$(".pin").on('click',function(){})` will not work as it will not find element with `.pin` class on page load. So, you need to assign a `click` event from the `document` reference as:

```
$(document).on('click','.pin', function(){
    pin = this.id;
    alert(pin);
});
```